# DistinctAsync against array sub documents with MongoDB C# 2.0 driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

In MongoDB 3.0 with the C# 2.0 driver, how do you get a distinct list of values using `DistinctAsync` from a document's array of sub documents?

I'm looking for the C# equivalent of this in the shell:

```
db.cars.distinct("parts.name", {"make":"Ford"})
```

After admitting defeat, I resorted to this shell-ish code:

```
var distinctParts = await db.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument {
    { "distinct", "cars"}, 
    {"key", "parts.name"},
    {"query", new BsonDocument { { "make", "Ford" }} } });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `await db.DistinctAsync<MyType>(...)` is not working for you, and what error(s) does it produce?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var filter = new  MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFilterDefinition<CARS_TYPE>(x => x.make == "ford");
var distinctParts = await cars_collection.DistinctAsync<string>("parts.name", filter);
```